# Check if file exists even on PATH

Tags: perl

I have something like this:

```
if(! -e $filename) {
    # do something
}
```

but I need to alter it so that it looks for file even on my PATH. Is there any way to achieve this without analysing PATH?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`File::Which`](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aWhich)

Comment: That should be fine really since what other files would you be interested in when referring to `PATH`. But all the same, it's worth pointing out.

Comment: That's a handy module. While many Perl distributions do come with `File::Which`, it is [not a core module](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-F.html), so you may have to install it with `[sudo] cpan File::Which`.

Answer (score 4):

How can you see if a file is in one of the directories specified in `$ENV{PATH}` without looking at `$ENV{PATH}`? … That's a rhetorical question.

Here is a [short script I wrote](http://www.unur.com/comp/ppp/multi-which.html) some time ago. You should be able to adapt it for your needs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use File::Basename;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile path );

my $myname = fileparse $0;
die "Usage: $myname program_name\n" unless @ARGV;

my @path = path;
my @pathext = ( q{} );

if ( $^O eq 'MSWin32' ) {
    push @pathext, map { lc } split /;/, $ENV{PATHEXT};
}

PROGRAM: for my $progname ( @ARGV ) {
    unless ( $progname eq fileparse $progname ) {
        warn "Not processed: $progname\n\tArgument is not a plain file name\n";
        next PROGRAM;
    }

    my @results;

    for my $dir ( @path ) {
        for my $ext ( @pathext ) {
            my $f = catfile $dir, "$progname$ext";
            push @results, $f if -x $f;
        }
    }

    print "$progname:\n";
    print "\t$_\n" for @results;
}
```

Comment: For splitting PATH multiplatform way, [File::Spec->path](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Spec#path) can be used to get them as list. No need to play with `$^O`.

Comment: **I already use `File::Spec->path`.** Note that `%PATHEXT%` is an entirely different thing which only is useful on Windows. And, I am not playing with `$^O`; I am inspecting it.

Comment: Oops, you are right. I will look better next time ... using PATHEXT is good idea to find executables on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The `PATH` variable is used by the system when loading executables. So to get the underlying system to do the work for you I believe you would need to attempt to load an executable. It doesn't sound like this is what you are looking to do.

There may well be some library that will offer such functionality but it is very simple to write your own. You just need to use `split` and then iterate.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [daxim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8243611/45375) and [Sinan Ünür's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8243770/45375) helpful answers:

In *limited* circumstances, if you only care *whether or not* a given program is in the system's path, you can take a *shortcut*:

*If* the target program is a CLI that has a side-effect-free option (other than producing stdout output) that causes the program to exit successfully very quickly - e.g., `--version` - you can do the following:

```
my $exe = 'bash';   # example
`$exe --version` || die "'$exe' not found.";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a core module, there's [`can_run()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Cmd.html#%24path-%3d-can_run(-PROGRAM-)%3b) from [IPC::Cmd](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Cmd).

```
use IPC::Cmd qw(can_run);
if (can_run($filename)) {
    # do something
}
```

The perldoc for [File::Which](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aWhich) points out the caveat that this will also search the current directory, even if that's not in your path:

> IPC::Cmd
>
> Comes with a "can_run" function with slightly different semantics that
>   the traditional UNIX where. It will find executables in the current
>   directory, even though the current directory is not searched for by
>   default on Unix.